# Why is the determinant of this matrix zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

I have a system of equations to solve $Ax = b$, but the determinant of matrix $A$ is zero.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

To me, none of the rows/columns of this matrix look dependent. I am wondering why the determinant of matrix $A$ is zero?

Also, how should I solve this system or estimate $x$?

Comment: Note that adding the first two rows and subtracting the third yields the fourth, so the row (and column) vectors are not linearly independent.

Comment: I think I see why you're confused -- there is a nice symmetry in this matrix that would indeed seem to suggest that it is full-rank, since all components of each basis vector contribute equally or "fairly". It definitely defies my intuition as well, so I guess this is yet another lesson that you shouldn't trust your intuition!

Comment: The sum of the first two is equal to the sum of the last two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $b=\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4\end{bmatrix}^T$ and consider the Gaussian elimination on the complete matrix:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
1&0&1&0&b_3\\
0&1&0&1&b_4
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&-1&1&0&b_3-b_1\\
0&1&0&1&b_4
\end{array}\right]
&&R_3\gets R_3-R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&1&-1&0&b_1-b_3\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&1&0&1&b_4
\end{array}\right]
&&R_3\leftrightarrow R_2,\quad R_2\gets-R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&1&-1&0&b_1-b_3\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&0&1&1&b_4-b_1+b_3
\end{array}\right]
&&R_4\gets R_4-R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&1&-1&0&b_1-b_3\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&0&0&0&b_4-b_1+b_3-b_2
\end{array}\right]
&&R_4\gets R_4-R_3
\tag{*}
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&b_1\\
0&1&0&1&b_1-b_3+b_2\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&0&0&0&b_4-b_1+b_3-b_2
\end{array}\right]
&&R_2\gets R_2+R_3
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&0&-1&b_3-b_2\\
0&1&0&1&b_1-b_3+b_2\\
0&0&1&1&b_2\\
0&0&0&0&b_4-b_1+b_3-b_2
\end{array}\right]
&&R_1\gets R_1-R_2
\end{align}
From the step marked as (*) we deduce that

1. the matrix $A$ has rank $3$ (hence zero determinant);
2. the system has solution if and only if $b_4-b_1+b_3-b_2=0$.

When $b_4-b_1+b_3-b_2=0$, the system has infinitely many solutions in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_3-b_2+h\\
b_1-b_3+b_2-h\\
b_2-h\\
h
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_3-b_2\\
b_1-b_3+b_2\\
b_2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+
h\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $h$ is any scalar.

Answer (score 13):

$$
(1,1,0,0)+(0,0,1,1)-(1,0,1,0)-(0,1,0,1)=(0,0,0,0) 
$$
so the rows are linearly *dependent*.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices):
$$
M=\left[\begin{array}[cc]\\A&B\\
C&D\end{array}\right]
$$
where $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ have the same order. If  $D$ be invertible then we have:
$$
\det(M)=\det(D)\cdot \det(A-BD^{-1}C)
$$
In your question $C=D=I_2$,the identity matrix of order $2$, which results that:
$$
\det(M)=\underbrace{\det(D)}_1\cdot \det(A-B)=\det(
\left[
\begin{array}[cc]
\\1&1\\
-1&-1
\end{array}
\right])=0
$$